# Ссылка на маркер в Leaflet

Tags: javascript, marker

Подскажите пожалуйста непрограммеру, - возможно ли в Leaflet сделать ссылку на маркер с другой страницы или с другого сайта. Т.е. возможно ли расшарить маркер?

Весь интернет перерыл, никаких примеров решения, кроме:
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/leaflet-js/link%20to%20marker/leaflet-js/l-3mdTlC5Bw/O1a9SYeKcdYJ
который не работает (пример кода ниже)

Сейчас я использую только ссылку на точку на карте с помощью leaflet.hash

> balimio.com/main/map/bali-map-full#5/43.213/19.116

А хотелось бы получить ссылку типа:

> balimio.com/main/map/bali-map-full#marker-1

часть кода из GeoJSON:

```
{
  "loc":[43.2, 19.1],
  "id": "marker-1",
  "title":"Tegenungan Waterfall",
  "info":"<img src='/img/2013/07/130707_01_304.jpg' />Tegenungan Waterfall"
},
```

часть кода из скрипта:

```
for(pp in pointsPlace) {
   var loc = pointsPlace[pp].loc,
       title = pointsPlace[pp].title,
       info = pointsPlace[pp].info,
       id = pointsPlace[pp].id,
       marker = new L.Marker(new L.latLng(loc), {title: title} );
   marker.bindPopup(info);
   markersLayer.addLayer(marker);
   ...
```

Comment: Расскажи как именно решил проблему пожалуйста.

Answer (score 1):

Используя только Leaflet сделать подобное нельзя.
Вы можете написать свой модуль на Javascript, который загружал бы данные маркера с сервера по указанном имени и отображал его на карте.

Comment: Спасибо.
В моем вопросе ключевое слово - непрограммер.
Но задачу уже решил:
http://balimio.com/main/map/bali-map-full#devils-tear-map